# How to determine if a parameter is a constexpr in compile-time

Tags: c++

I have a compile-time string class that helps programs compute various relevant things at compile time, such as hash results and a quick lookup table for find, which is constructed like this:

```cpp
"hello"_constexpr_str;
```

Also, my string class supports construction from this type, which allows for fast hash and fast find and avoids unnecessary data copying, like this.

```cpp
defs::string string = "hello"_constexpr_str;
```

Of course, my string class also supports building from `const char_T*`

**Now here's the problem!**

I want to use the constexpr method automatically when my string class is constructed with compile-time constants like `string("hell word!")` rather than ugly but strong `string("hell word!"_constexpr_str)`

In other words, I want `string("hell word!")` to automatically become `string("hell word!"_constexpr_str)` in compile-time to calculate the information about the constant string and put it in constant state storage, so that all my string class has to do is hold a pointer to constexpr_str_t

```cpp
//Draft Code
#if defined(__cpp_if_consteval)
    #define if_in_consteval if consteval
#else
    #define if_in_consteval if constexpr(0)
#endif
constexpr string_t(const constexpr_str_t&str)noexcept;//save a pointer to constexpr_str_t
string_t(const char_T* str)noexcept{
    if_in_consteval{
        constexpr constexpr_str_t constexpr_str(str);
        construct[this](constexpr_str);
    }
    else{
        construct[this](string_view_t(str));
    }
}
```

What do I do to achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear if you're trying to detect whether it is a constant expression as distinct from whether it is a string literal. I mean, the behavior of your class is the same either way.

Comment: `constexpr constexpr_str_t constexpr_str(str);` will never work. A function parameter is not usable in a constant expression ever. You need to encode the value of the string in its type or pass it as template argument to make that work. It would be easier to make suggestions if you added some example on how you want to use this (and why).

Comment: @user17732522 : All I wanted to do was to make string("xxx") work exactly the same as string("xxx"_constexpr_str), without the need to add these endings for optimization

Comment: @steve02081504 But how do they currently differ? What is the observable difference between the two?

Comment: How is `operator""_constexpr_str` declared? Is it `constexpr` or `consteval`? What does the `string_t(const constexpr_str_t&str)` overload do differently than the `else` branch of `string_t(const char_T* str)`? What is `construct`?

Comment: @user17732522 constexpr_str_t contains preprocessing information for some common algorithms calculated at compile time, which can be used to speed up things like string lookups and hashes. And constexpr_str_t also contains the content of the string itself, so you don't have to allocate memory for the content during string construction.

Comment: If your question is whether it is possible to overload `consteval` in such a way that it will fall back to a non-`consteval` overload if the `consteval` overload doesn't work because it doesn't result in a constant expression, then no, that is not possible in the language currently, but is would practically be almost the same as just using `constexpr` instead of `consteval` anyway.

Comment: @user17732522 `template<constexpr_str_t_literal_helper str_helper>[[nodiscard]]inline consteval auto& operator ""_constexpr_str()noexcept` Unfortunately this is the function marked as consteval, in case I didn't explain it clearly, you can look at [this](https://github.com/ELC-lang/ELC/blob/149a400145c638923b672cf80b7f67dc0b208de0/parts/header_file/files/elc/_files/base_defs/base_defs/constexpr_str.hpp#L41L78).

Comment: @user17732522 In the linked code there is `constexpr_str_t_literal_helper` type and `literal_result_provider` type for each string literal and the `constexpr_str_t` type just has corresponding type for each type of char, are you reading it wrong?

Comment: @steve02081504 Yes, I did. Sorry about that. Doesn't change though that what you want to do won't be possible. It seems you basically want to overload `consteval` on whether or not the argument is a constant expression. That is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question now after the discussion in the comments correctly, you have a `operator""_constexpr_str` which is marked `consteval` and returns a string-view-like type `constexpr_str_t` with some additional information attached based on the contents of the string.

You then have a function taking an (ordinary) string literal as argument with overloads taking either `constexpr_str_t` or `const char*`. You basically want the `const char*` overload to only be chosen when the argument is not a constant expression. Otherwise the `constexpr_str_t` overload should be chosen and constructed at compile-time (i.e. via `consteval`) so that the extra information can be attached at compile-time.

This cannot work however, because it is impossible to overload on `consteval`. Whether or not a `consteval` function is called depends only on the type of the argument. It is not possible to distinguish between constant expression arguments and non-constant expression arguments.

Trying to determine whether a function argument is a constant expression *inside* a function is also impossible. Functions are compiled individually. They are not compiled twice depending on whether or not the argument is a constant expression.

The only thing possible is to change behavior based on whether the whole expression that the function call is used in is a context requiring a constant expression. That is what `if consteval` is for. But if you are making a decision based on such a scenario, you don't need

```
constexpr constexpr_str_t constexpr_str(str);
```

You can simply do the calculation for the additional properties of the string there as if at runtime and mark the function `constexpr`. If used in a context requiring a constant expression it will be evaluated at compile-time.

If you want to enforce this even if the call doesn't happen in a context requiring a constant expression, then it is impossible.

You can however write a macro which tests whether an expression is a constant expression and then conditionally calls either a `consteval` function or a non-`consteval` function. It is just impossible through a function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C++20 [`std::is_constant_evaluated()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) function found in the `<type_traits>` header. It detects whether a function call occurs within a constant-evaluated context.

Comment: But can I construct constexprs from parameters when I'm sure this is happening in a constant-evaluated context?

Comment: @steve02081504: What do you mean "construct constexprs from parameters"? A parameter is *never* a constant expression. It can be used by constant expression functions, but the parameter itself can't be used to initialize a `constexpr` variable or something.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've modified the problem description to make it clearer that I want to calculate the information about the constant string at compile time and put it in constant state storage, so that all my string class has to do is hold a pointer to constexpr_str_t

Comment: @steve02081504: "*calculate the information about the constant string at compile time and put it in constant state storage*" Um... how do you expect *that* to happen? You can't modify global state during constant evaluation. So how does this "constant state storage" work? Are you sure this stuff is running at compile time and not runtime?

Comment: @NicolBolas : All I can think of is that if string("xxx"_constexpr_str) can do it, why can't I find a way to make string("xxx") do it too?
I didn't think too much about the syntax, and to be honest, I just wanted to avoid adding these unnecessary end-falls to optimise efficiency

Comment: @steve02081504: "*if string("xxx"_constexpr_str) can do it*" Can do what? The thing you have described is not possible. Constexpr code cannot write to global mutable state. Odds are good that you're not getting compile-time execution here.

Comment: @steve02081504 The `string_t(const constexpr_str_t&str)` overload can't use the value of the string in a constant expression either, no matter whether the argument to the parameter is a constant expression.